# How to get iphone like animation for button in android

Tags: android, animation

I saw one iphone application if the button is visible and we press cancel button then that button should gone. in that case there is animation "the button diposes from left to right and finally got vanished". In android i am able to rotate any view or move it from left to right. But how can i get the effect that the button destroy animation and make a button visible in that type of animation.

Thanks

Deepak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to do, but it *seems* like you want to fade the button as well as translating it. If that's the case, then you can use alpha animations to change the opacity of the button. By gradually reducing the alpha to 0, the button will appear to fade away.

I have recently completed a series on animations on my blog. It is probably best to read the articles in order starting with the [first](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129), but the [final article](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/171) covers animating individual widgets.

Comment: Hi Mark, your response is very much useful for me

Answer (score 1):

To get a general idea of animations in android, check out this awesome page on quick actions. There is plenty of code and working animations with different options so you can get a full tutorial of how they work.

[How to create quick action dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)